# Assign Coupon only after customer opens email - SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, landing-page

I would like to know how to assign Coupon only after email is open.

We don't want to assign coupons to 50K customers and only 2K customers open the email. I'm unnecessarily assigning 48K coupons (Unused).

Support suggested to use new content builder, with QueryParameter to update the DE and also to display the coupon in the Landing page.

I am not sure about this process

Comment: Finally achieved through Cloud pages and also using AMP script (Claim row functionality)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're looking for [**Live Offers**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_live_offers.htm&type=5):

> Use live offers in Email Studio to manage the creation and distribution of live content coupons sent to your subscriber base.
>
> Coupons render offers on email landing page when the recipient opens a message. Associate a coupon code with each offer. Each coupon uses a dynamic image to display the correct content for the time a recipient opens a message or visits a page.
>
> Coupons using Live Content offer you the ability to control the availability of your offers. For example, if you distribute 500 coupon codes to a list of 1000 subscribers, the first 500 subscribers to open the offer see the offer and coupon code. The next 400 subscribers who open their email see an alternative image informing them that no more coupons are available. You can then use that message as a list acquisition strategy. The remaining 100 subscribers may never open their email or delete it.

Comment: Note that Live Offers is an extra paid service for SFMC, meaning for most that it is added cost on top of your annual subscription.

Comment: We are using live Offers, untill now we were assigning coupon to customer with a query and Sending emails. please provide me some more information so that I can explore further.

Comment: @adam spriggs, please let me know how to implement this... example, if you distribute 500 coupon codes to a list of 1000 subscribers, the first 500 subscribers to open the offer see the offer and coupon code. The next 400 subscribers who open their email see an alternative image informing them that no more coupons are available. You can then use that message as a list acquisition strategy. The remaining 100 subscribers may never open their email or delete it.